# Chess knowledge and understanding

Tags: learning, strategy, tactics

I am not a beginner, but I am absolutely not a practicing chess player, although I would like for that to change. I am inquiring about which direction I should take in advancing my abilities and understanding of the game. I am probably a 1300-1500 level player, but it is all free wheeling and personal experience. I haven't studied much and I am starting to realize that I am not going to improve if I don't actively work on my game. Hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction! Thanks!

Comment: There are probably already a couple of questions on this site addressing this (e.g. [this one](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/what-advice-would-you-give-a-novice-in-chess?rq=1)).

Comment: Yeah, you better search the site...

Answer (score 1):

Generally the first advice is always to train lots of tactics.

That means you should start solving tactical exercises regularly. On your level this will lead to rapid improvement. You can train online on a [variety](http://www.wtharvey.com) of [sites](http://chesstempo.com) or get a good beginner's book.

The second important point is just to play. Over time you will get an idea of where your weaknesses are and you can start to look up opening lines, specific endgames or strategic themes.